# How to call matrices which have a specific character string in their name from a list of matrices?

Tags: r, string, matrix, select, extract

Do you have an idea to call only one specific matrix which contain a string of characters in my list of twelve matrices ? For exemple, I have my list of twelve matrices (which represent data of genetic distance between pairs of 60 individuals, a matrix is therefore 60*60) for the 12 months of the year, and I want to extract only 3 matrices for 3 months of the year.
So for that, I want to call the matrices which contain in their name "Apr", "May" or "Jun", like this : `spring <- list(list.mat[["Apr"]], list.mat[["May"]], list.mat[["Jun"]])`. But because there is missing months, I want to find a function who call only the months who can possibly contain these string of charactrs in their names. I try `grep` function and its derivates but it doesn't work on list of matrices...
I know there is a simple way to do that but I don't know which way to look!

I don't want to make it manually because I have more than 40 list of 12 matrices !

Thanks for any replies if you know what i'm looking for

Comment: You can use `[` i.e. `list.mat[c("Apr", "May", "Jun")]`

Comment: I try as well but because I have missing months (for exemple only april and may for certain year), my list of matrices `spring` contains `NULL` matrices, which bothers me. Maybe I can delete them with a `ifesle` but I thought there was an easier way.. Thanks btw

Comment: If there are NULL matrices, you can `Filter` i.e. `Filter(Negate(is.null), list.mat)`

Comment: Also `list.mat[names(list.mat) %in% c("Apr", "May", "Jun")]` will extract just the ones that are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `Filter` from `base R` to remove the `NULL` list elements

```
Filter(Negate(is.null), list.mat)
```